# How do I indicate a newer version of a "Dataset"?

Tags: schema.org

I would like to include newer versions for a `Dataset` that has been superseded.

For example, *Some dataset V1* has been replaced by *Some dataset V2*. The landing page for *V1* no longer has data, but instead points to the landing page for *V2*.

How do I indicate a newer version of a `Dataset` in Schema.org markup?

Schema.org properties `replacer` and `supersededBy` are not recognized for an object of type `Dataset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org doesn’t provide a property to link a `Dataset` to an updated `Dataset`.

An unspecified relation might be conveyed by referencing them from the same [`DataCatalog`](http://schema.org/DataCatalog). In some contexts it might also make sense to use [`isBasedOn`](http://schema.org/isBasedOn) to link the new one from the old one.

You can provide data about the datasets that could convey which one is the newest:

- You can specify the version number of a dataset with the [`version`](http://schema.org/version) property.
- You can specify the creation/modification/publication dates of a dataset with the [`dateCreated`](http://schema.org/dateCreated), [`dateModified`](http://schema.org/dateModified), and [`datePublished`](http://schema.org/datePublished) properties. (And if it makes sense in your context, maybe also [`expires`](http://schema.org/expires).)

Example:

```html
<article typeof="schema:Dataset" resource="/dataset/v1#this">
  <link property="schema:url" href="/dataset/v1">
  <link property="schema:includedInDataCatalog" typeof="schema:DataCatalog" href="/dataset#this">
  <h2>
    <span property="schema:name">Some dataset</span>
    V<span property="schema:version">1</span>
  </h2>
  <time property="schema:datePublished">2017-05-30</time>
</article>

<article typeof="schema:Dataset" resource="/dataset/v2#this">
  <link property="schema:url" href="/dataset/v2">
  <link property="schema:includedInDataCatalog" typeof="schema:DataCatalog" href="/dataset#this">
  <h2>
    <span property="schema:name">Some dataset</span>
    V<span property="schema:version">2</span>
  </h2>
  <time property="schema:datePublished">2018-01-22</time>
</article>
```

In case you don’t offer, nor need to say something about, nor need to reference older datasets, you could of course decide to have only *one* `Dataset` and update its `dateModified` property.

Comment: I am using version and the creation/modification/publication dates. Expires does not make sense for me because the newer versions are not scheduled. What I am doing now is providing the metadata for superseded datasets without including any `DataDownload` links.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Looks like it might be time to make a suggestion to schema.org.